# Split First name and Last name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I have a user with the name **Paul Steve Panakkal**. It's a long name it won't fit to the div container. So is there anyway to split first name and last name from it using JavaScript or jQuery?

The name is got from PHP into a variable in JavaScript. This is then splitted using JS.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with those parts then? What makes up a first name and what a last name?

Comment: Worth noting, you should never make **any** assumptions about a name: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: How about using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-full-name

Comment: I used https://github.com/joshfraser/JavaScript-Name-Parser

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You should use the [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method:

```
'Paul Steve Panakkal'.split(' '); // returns ["Paul", "Steve", "Panakkal"]
```

You can use it this way:

```
'Paul Steve Panakkal'.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' '); // returns "Paul Steve"
'Paul Steve Panakkal'.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' '); // returns "Panakkal"
```

So in common:

```
var firstName = fullName.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
var lastName = fullName.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');
```

Comment: The problem with `.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(' ')` for first name is that if the string only contains one letter, it fails to give the first name.

Comment: Using your method first name would be "Paul Steve" and last name "Panakkal". What if want first name to be "Paul" and last name "Steve Panakkal" -- which means last name would be everything after the first white space. How to do it?

Comment: Also how would this solution work if they have two (highly likely) or four names (not so much)?

Comment: In addition, what happens if there's a leading white space? It would be a good idea to "trim" the strings before splitting/slicing them.. like so `str.replace(/\s+/g, '')`

Answer (score 47):

Yes:

```
var fullName = "Paul Steve Panakkal".split(' '),
    firstName = fullName[0],
    lastName = fullName[fullName.length - 1];
```

References:

- [`string.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: If you only put in "Paul" as the full name, it will use Paul as the first and last name...

Answer (score 26):

In Spanish it can be tricky because you may have a second optional name and even complex surnames like "del Bosque" or "de la Hoya", vowels with accent marks and the *ñ*. The following javascript is capabable of parsing a full spanish name, having in count you are writting it respecting the upper and lower cases. It will return a json giving you

1. **name**: 1 or 2 main names
2. **lastName**: the main lastname
3. **secondLastName**: The second lastname

The code is:

```
function parseName(input) {
        var fullName = input || "";
        var result = {};

        if (fullName.length > 0) {
            var nameTokens = fullName.match(/[A-ZÁ-ÚÑÜ][a-zá-úñü]+|([aeodlsz]+\s+)+[A-ZÁ-ÚÑÜ][a-zá-úñü]+/g) || [];

            if (nameTokens.length > 3) {
                result.name = nameTokens.slice(0, 2).join(' ');
            } else {
                result.name = nameTokens.slice(0, 1).join(' ');
            }

            if (nameTokens.length > 2) {
                result.lastName = nameTokens.slice(-2, -1).join(' ');
                result.secondLastName = nameTokens.slice(-1).join(' ');
            } else {
                result.lastName = nameTokens.slice(-1).join(' ');
                result.secondLastName = "";
            }
        }

        return result;
}
```

The surnames are required if you are going to specify a second name. Try it out with:

- Vicente Hernández Planes
- Oscar de la Hoya
- José Julian Martí Pérez
- Manuel de Céspedes del Castillo
- Calixto García Íñiguez

Even try out a complex one like

- María de la Caridad del Bosque y Loynáz

Comment your experiences with it.

Answer (score 16):

I think, it's time to get started with regular expressions :)

```
"Paul Steve Panakkal".split(/(\s).+\s/).join("") // "Paul Panakkal"
```

Comment: This will work fine as long you are not supporting Spanish names.

Comment: @darol100 Could you post any example please?

Comment: Spanish name has two last names. My name is a great example: "Darryl Norris Marquez".split(/(\s).+\s/).join("") // "Darryl Marquez", which is not right. Norris Marquez is my last name. However, I do not think there is a good way to identify a Spanish last name VS a middle name. See @EliuX for more details on how to support Spanish last name.

Answer (score 16):

The most common solution, where we always take the first word for the first name and the rest for the last name:

```js
const splitName = (name = '') => {
  const [firstName, ...lastName] = name.split(' ').filter(Boolean);
  return {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName.join(' ')
  }
}

console.log(splitName('Jon  Snow'));

console.log(splitName(' Jon '));

console.log(splitName(' Jon The    White Wolf '));
```

Answer (score 4):

Extended version of Speransky Danil's answer which handles the case where the supplied string has only one word in it.

```
/**
 * Gets the first name, technically gets all words leading up to the last
 * Example: "Blake Robertson" --> "Blake"
 * Example: "Blake Andrew Robertson" --> "Blake Andrew"
 * Example: "Blake" --> "Blake"
 * @param str
 * @returns {*}
 */
exports.getFirstName = function(str) {
    var arr = str.split(' ');
    if( arr.length === 1 ) {
        return arr[0];
    }
    return arr.slice(0, -1).join(' '); // returns "Paul Steve"
}

/**
 * Gets the last name (e.g. the last word in the supplied string)
 * Example: "Blake Robertson" --> "Robertson"
 * Example: "Blake Andrew Robertson" --> "Robertson"
 * Example: "Blake" --> "<None>"
 * @param str
 * @param {string} [ifNone] optional default value if there is not last name, defaults to "<None>"
 * @returns {string}
 */
exports.getLastName = function(str, ifNone) {
    var arr = str.split(' ');
    if(arr.length === 1) {
        return ifNone || "<None>";
    }
    return arr.slice(-1).join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried below code and it works cool for me

```
var full_name = 'xyz abc pqr';
var name = full_name.split(' ');
var first_name = name[0];
var last_name = full_name.substring(name[0].length.trim());
```

In above example:

(1)

```
If full_name = 'xyz abc pqr';
first_name = "xyz";
last_name = "abc pqr";
```

(2)

```
If `full_name = "abc"`:
Then first_name = "abc";
and last_name = "";
```

Comment: It should be `full_name.substring(name[0].length).trim();` with the trim function at the end

Answer (score 4):

A comenter said What if want first name to be "Paul" and last name "Steve Panakkal"

```js
var name = "Paul Steve Panakkal" // try "Paul", "Paul Steve"
var first_name = name.split(' ')[0]
var last_name = name.substring(first_name.length).trim()
console.log(first_name)
console.log(last_name)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code, it works for me

```js
let name = "Paul Steve Panakkal"
let parts = name.split(' ')
let firstName = parts.shift();  // Paul
let lastName = parts.join(' '); // Steve Panakkal

console.log({
firstName,
lastName
})
```

Comment: I also use this one and I dare to say this method is the cleanest and easiest to read.

Answer (score 3):

if you assume the last word is the last name and a single word name is also a last name then ...

```
var items = theName.split(' '),
    lastName = items[items.length-1],
    firstName = "";

for (var i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
   if (i > 0) {
      firstName += ' ';
   }
   firstName += items[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Watch out for edge-cases like only a first name being provided or two or more spaces being entered. If you only want to parse out the first and last name, this will do the trick (full name should always contain at least 1 character to avoid first_name being set to an empty string):

```
var full_name_split = "Paul Steve Panakkal".split(" ");
var first_name = full_name_split[0];
var last_name = full_name_split.length > 1 ? full_name_split[full_name_split.length - 1] : null;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to Archive this.

I think the easiest way is to split and pop the last name.

```js
let fullname = 'Paul Steve Panakkal'; // from php

let tmpArray = fullname.split(' '); //split the name to an array

const lastname = tmpArray.pop(); // pop the last element of the aray and store it in "lastname" variable
const firstname = tmpArray.join(' '); // join the array to make first and middlename and store it in "firstname" variale

console.log("firstname:", firstname)
console.log("lastname:", lastname)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

You'll need to change the line: `splitFullName("firstName","lastName","fullName");` and make sure it includes the right field IDs from your form.

---

```
function splitFullName(a,b,c){
    String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
        return this.replace( /(^|\s)([a-z])/g , function(m,p1,p2){ return p1+p2.toUpperCase(); } );
    };
    document.getElementById(c).oninput=function(){
        fullName = document.getElementById(c).value;
        if((fullName.match(/ /g) || []).length ===0 || fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(" ")+1,fullName.length) === ""){
            first = fullName.capitalize();;
            last = "null";
        }else if(fullName.substring(0,fullName.indexOf(" ")).indexOf(".")>-1){
            first = fullName.substring(0,fullName.indexOf(" ")).capitalize() + " " + fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(" ")+1,fullName.length).substring(0,fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(" ")+1,fullName.length).indexOf(" ")).capitalize();
            last = fullName.substring(first.length +1,fullName.length).capitalize();
        }else{
            first = fullName.substring(0,fullName.indexOf(" ")).capitalize();
            last = fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(" ")+1,fullName.length).capitalize();
        }
        document.getElementById(a).value = first;
        document.getElementById(b).value = last;
    };
    //Initial Values
    if(document.getElementById(c).value.length === 0){
        first = document.getElementById(a).value.capitalize();
        last = document.getElementById(b).value.capitalize();
        fullName =  first + " " + last ;
        console.log(fullName);
        document.getElementById(c).value = fullName;
    }
}

//Replace the ID's below with your form's field ID's
splitFullName("firstName","lastName","fullName");
```

---

Source: http://developers.marketo.com/blog/add-a-full-name-field-to-a-marketo-form/

Answer (score 2):

You needn't use any **split** method and create unnecessary arrays for that operation. Just use **lastIndexOf** and **substring** methods of javascript.

```
var s = "Paul Steve Panakkal";
var a = s.lastIndexOf(' '); // last occurence of space
var b = s.substring(0, a); // Paul Steve
var c = s.substring(a+1); // Panakkal
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const fullName = 'Paul Steve Panakkal'.split(' ');
const lastName = fullName.pop(); // 'Panakkal'
const firstName = fullName.join(' '); // 'Paul Steve'
console.log(firstName);
console.log(lastName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstName = fullName.split(" ")[0];
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative could be using regular expression.

```
\w+\s\w+(?=\s)|\w+
```

The above regex will find `firstName` and `lastName` string pattern which matches two or three combinations of naming types.

```js
const regex = /\w+\s\w+(?=\s)|\w+/g;

const name1 = 'Paul Steve Panakkal';
const [firstName1, lastName1] = name1.trim().match(regex);
console.log(`${firstName1} | ${lastName1}`);

const name2 = 'John Doe';
const [firstName2, lastName2] = name2.trim().match(regex);
console.log(`${firstName2} | ${lastName2}`);
```

**Details**

- `\w+` Match any word character.
- `?=\s` Match any whitespace character but not catching it.

Answer (score 1):

This function will break any name into first name and last name storing the last word as the last name and everything else as the first name. It returns an object which contains the separated names:

```js
function parseName(fullName) {
  const name = fullName.split(' ')
  const person = {}
  if (name.length > 1) {
    person.lastName = name.pop()
    person.firstName = name.join(' ')
  } else {
    person.lastName = ""
    person.firstName = obj.name
  }
  return person
}

console.log(parseName("Ashak Zahin Hasan"))
// { firstName: "Ashak Zahin", lastName: "Hasan" }
```

Answer (score 0):

use JS `split` with space as delimitter.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the last name is all the names after the first name, just use:

```
var name = "Paul Steve Panakkal";
var arrName = name.split(" ");
var firstName = arrName.slice(0, 1).join(' ');
var lastName = arrName.slice(1, arrName.length).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

This way, both firstName and lastName are always correct

```
var names = fullName.split(' ');
if (!names || names.length <= 1) {
   firstName = this.name;
   lastName = '';
} else {
   firstName = names.slice(0, -1).join(' ');
   lastName = names.slice(-1).join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fullName = "Paul Steve Panakkal";
```

You can use the split function to split the full name then the result like displaying elements in an array or list.

This is what happens when you use the split function.

```
fullName.split(" ")

["Paul", "Steve", "Panakkal"]
```

This is not saved to any variable. You can perform the split function and assign an element to a well defined variable like this.

```
var firstName = fullName.split(" ")[0];

var lastName = fullName.split(" ")[1];

var otherName = fullName.split(" ")[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this logic:

```
const fullName = "Paul Steve Panakkal";
const idx = fullName.lastIndexOf(' ');
const firstName = idx !== -1 ? fullName.substring(0, idx) : fullName;
const lastName = idx !== -1 ? fullName.substring(idx + 1) : '';
console.log('firstName:', firstName, 'lastName:', lastName);
```

output:

```
firstName: Paul Steve lastName: Panakkal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"  Paul Steve   ".trim().split(/(\s).+\s/).join("")  // 'Paul Steve'
```

You should add **trim()** just in case the user accidentally types an extra whitespace!

Comment: could you explain what your whole code does? You've only explained that trim() removes any leading and trailing whitespace

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last name to be all the names after the first name:

```
function splitFirstLast(name) {
  return {
    firstName: name.indexOf(' ') !== -1 && name.substring(0, name.indexOf(' ')) || name,
    lastName: name.indexOf(' ') !== -1 && name.substring(name.indexOf(' ') + 1) || ''
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects can do the Trick with a simple function:

```js
    const fullName = "Edgar Allan Poe"

    const formatter = (name) => {

        const splitedName = name.trim().split(' ')

        if(splitedName.length === 0) return ""

        //here happens the hack!, it prevents duplicate names
        //JS objects overrides duplicate keys, very useful here 
        const output = {
            [splitedName[0]]: splitedName[0],
            //storing first key

            [splitedName[splitedName.length - 1]]: splitedName[splitedName.length - 1] 
            //storing last key (whose may be first key)
        }

        return Object.keys(output).join(' ').trim()
        //now convert object keys into a string. "E pronto rs"

    }

    console.log(formatter(fullName)) // "Edgar Poe"
    console.log(formatter("Elias")) // "Elias"
    console.log(formatter("")) // ""
```