# Spliting name and pushing to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array like this:

```
var abc = [
    "Ken Robert Smith",
    "Daniel Johnson"
]
```

How to split words in this array and push to new one that have first name(s) and surname separately? Any number of first names should be in first column and if there is only a surname it should go to 2nd column.

Im learning JavaScript. I tried some for loops and `split()` but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Homework problem?

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split First name and Last name using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340789/split-first-name-and-last-name-using-javascript)

Comment: I didnt realy achived anything. I tried making function Split() and then for loop this in every element, but my js expirience is about a week.
Its not a homework. Ive just set myself a goal to achive.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some sample code would be useful, but in rough terms, you're going to want to do the following.

Iterate over the array. For each element in the array, split it by whitespace (.split()), then push the first element of your split element into your first name array, and the last element (which you can access at index -1) to the last name array.

I'll leave the actual code as an exercise to the student.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store the names, assuming you don't want duplicates.

```
var abc = [ "Ken Robert Smith", "Daniel Johnson", "Ken Johnson" ];

const result = abc.reduce( ( result, name ) => {
  const names = name.split( /\s+/g );

  const surname = names.pop( );

  result.surnames.add( surname );
  names.forEach( name => result.firstNames.add( name ) );

  return result;
}, {firstNames: new Set, surnames: new Set} );

console.log( result.firstNames ); // Set(3) {"Ken", "Robert", "Daniel"}
console.log( result.surnames ); // Set(2) {"Smith", "Johnson"}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, only the last word is the last name, and the rest are the "first name".

I would split the name by space into an array, pop off the last element (last name), and then join the remaining elements to make the first name.  Like this:

```js
var abc = [
    "Ken Robert Smith",
    "Daniel Johnson"
];

var out = abc.map(function (el) {
  var b = el.split(" ");
  var ln = b.pop();
  return [b.join(" "), ln];
});

console.log(out);
```