# How split first name and last name in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, function, split

I know that this question maybe it is duplicate from other ones, but I try everything and use this [stack overflow foro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340789/split-first-name-and-last-name-using-javascript) to get the first name and last name from a fullname input but the nodejs console show me lot of errors, the most commonly is **separar.split is not a function**.

Would you help me to try to fix the problem?..

```
function create(req, res) {
    var body = req.body;

    var separar = {
        nombrecompleto: body.nombrecompleto,
    }
    var userData = {
        rolid: body.rolid,
        nombre: separar.split[separar].slice(0, -1).join(" "),
        // apellido: separar.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' '),
        username: body.username,
        pasword: body.pasword,
        usermail: body.usermail
    }

    console.log(userData);

    users.create(userData).then(usuario => {
        return res.status(201).json({
            ok: true,
            usuario
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).json({
            ok: false,
            message: 'Oops.! We have had an error here',
            err
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Removing the `postgresql` tag since it does not seem related to it in any way.

Comment: `separar` is not a `string`. It is an `object`. `object` doesn't have a `split` function. Check it out [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: split() is a JavaScript string method. you can only use it on a string, example: `var names = "firstname lastname".split(" ");`

Answer (score 0):

You are using string.split method of javascript on an object separar.
Try using it on a string i.e separar.nombrecompleto.

-- Hope it helps!